# Calculated member datatype changing

Tags: mdx

I have a problem with my measure datatype.Look at the below code:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Contribution] AS
    Format(
        IIF(
            IsEmpty([Measures].[Detail_Net_Sales]),0,[Measures].[Detail_Net_Sales]                 )/
           [Measures].[SumTotalPayable] 
           )
    SELECT  
      {[Measures].[Contribution]} 
   ON COLUMNS,
      Order(
           [DIMProduct].[ProductCode].[ProductCode].AllMEMBERS,
           [Measures].[Contribution],
           BDESC
           ) 
   ON ROWS 
  FROM [Model] }
```

this code will return following result

```
ProductCode Contribution                       
----------- ------------                                            
123          17.56      
332          17.30       
245          16          
656          15.90
```

the problem is : if i omit the `Format` function `Order` function will not work correctly but if i don't `Contribution` will not have the correct datatype and will be convertd to text. hence i can not use it as i want. 
Any Suggestion?

Comment: Which data type do you get without the `Format`? What do you mean by "will not work correctly"? How does it work? What are you expecting?